Why is $d\tau^2 = -ds^2$?
Assume $c = 1$ and $-+++$ metric. Then, we know that the proper time, $d\tau$, is related to the spacetime interval, $ds$ as follows:
$$d\tau^2= -ds^2$$
The intuitive reason I believe, is that for a timelike separation, the spacetime interval between two events is negative. So if you integrate along the worldline, the answer will be negative, so you have to multiply by $-1$ in order to get a positive value, which is defined as the proper time (since it is along the worldline).
However, we know that
$ds^2 = -dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$.
and $dt = \gamma d\tau$
Then why isn't the answer equal to:
$ds^2 = -\gamma^2d\tau^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$
So how can it be consistent that both $d\tau^2 = -ds^2$ and $dt = \gamma d\tau$?

An interesting exercise related to this: using the Minkowski metric $\mathrm{d}s^2=c^2 \mathrm{d}\tau^2=c^2 \mathrm{d}t^2-\mathrm{d}x^2-\mathrm{d}y^2-\mathrm{d}z^2$, find $\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\tau}$. It should give you the classic formula for the Lorentz factor $\gamma$.

@controlgroup It should result in $\gamma=\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$? Can you give me some steps to arrive at this result?

Oh nvm I can see how it works

Consider an object in its rest frame. At two different times the object is in the same place $dx = dy = dz = 0$ and the velocity of the frame is $0$ so $\gamma = 1$

This is in my opinion one of the more elegant results of GR: do all the complex calculations for coordinate time from an external frame and see the metric as being highly complex, and you still always get $c\mathrm{d}\tau$ for the proper-time version of the equation. +1
